# testing an ember app - ember.js find() helper acceptable selectors

Tags: jquery, testing, ember.js, qunit, ember-app-kit

Trying to test-drive my first ember.js app. Using ember app kit.

Puzzled by how qunit works with selectors (I assumed that jquery selectors would work, and they do - for the most part...).

My handlebars has this code:

```
{{#link-to 'locations.new' classNames='add-btn'}}
  Add new location
{{/link-to}}
```

and I intend to test for existence of a link with an appropriate `href` and also click the link and verify the current url and route after click.

So, my tests are as follows:

```
// There is an element that links to locations/new
var link = find('a[href="#/locations/new"]');
ok(link, 'There is a link to add new location on the page');

click(link);
andThen(function() {
  equal(currentRouteName(), 'locations.new', 'Clicked "add" button - now locations.new route is active');
  equal(currentURL(), '/locations/new', 'Clicked "add" button - and current url is /locations/new');
});
```

*note: I am using `currentRouteName` and `currentURL` helpers from [this PR on EAK](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit/pull/363/), and they do work as intended.*

My test fails on the `click(link)` part, with `Error: Element [object Object] not found.`.

If I try to pass the selector directly to click - like so - `click("a[href='#/locations/new']")` - I get an error `Element a[href='#/locations/new'] not found.`. Same result if I try to escape the special character # with a backslash or double backslash.

For the time being, I mitigated the issue by grabbing the div by class - like so:

```
var link-by-class = find('.add-btn');
click(link-by-class);
andThen( as above )
```

And the tests pass.

Questions:

1. how come I can't invoke "click()" on the same variable found by href?
2. Am I testing with reasonable indifference to implementation? (well, the workaround of finding an element by the class doesn't fit that bill?)

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

Per [kingpin2k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1257694/kingpin2k)'s comment, my test was passing due to the wrong assertion method I chose - `ok(foo, 'bar')` will pass if `foo` is an empty array (which `find` returns if there are no results. Ember API docs guided me to use [findWithAssert](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Test.html#method_findWithAssert), and it fails to find the link with such `href`.

Befuddlingly, using the `[attribute='value']` jquery selector per [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) in JS console works; and the implementation of [find](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.3.0/packages/ember-testing/lib/helpers.js#L129-L135) as well as [findWithAssert](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.3.0/packages/ember-testing/lib/helpers.js#L121-L127) in ember-testing seems to just pass down the selector to jQuery...

Why does it fail? I don't know. One would think as GLaDOS explained [speedy thing goes in, speedy thing comes out](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MjeMOhb9enI) - just passing the selector over to jQuery would give it back as jQuery would return it - but apparently not.

I'll stick to using the class selector then, although it does kind of dictate implementation.

Comment: I think click accepts a selector, not a element. Could you try click('a[href="#/locations/new"]') instead?

Comment: Could it be because # is a special char (http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), can you try escaping it in your selector and see if that does the trick.

Comment: @MartinElvar I thought so too - but using click('a[href="#/locations/new"]') results in an error as follows: Element a[href='#/locations/new'] not found.

Comment: are you navigating to the route containing that link?  just a fyi, the find selector can return an empty array if nothing is found and an empty array is truthy... aka `ok([], 'everything is good')` will work just fine.  `ok(find('blahblah').length, 'everything is good')` would work better, or `equal(find('blahblah').length, 1, 'there is 1 blahblah element')`

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Deewendra, and big ups @kingpin2k I didn't realize an empty array would pass the `ok` test. Let me try this stuff. FWIW - such jquery selector does find the proper link in JS console in dev tools, so it is valid jquery at least...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

refusing to give up on making the test implementation-agnostic, I decided to use basic selectors, and discovered the undocumented culprit of my failures.

First, I wanted to get all links - and filter them by `href` attribute:

```
  var links = findWithAssert('a');
  var my-link = links.filter('[href="#/location/new"]');
```

That gave me a correct length of `links`, but `my-link` was still empty. So I alerted all hrefs, to be sure I'm not missing anything:

```
  for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++){
    alert(links[i].getAttribute('href'));
  }
```

And to my surprise I saw hrefs alerted without the leading `#`.

**Answer:**
When using complex css selectors with `href` attribute in ember.js `find()` helper, drop the hash from the url.